# Сохранение измененного и нового txt файла по определенному пути

Tags: java

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать сохранение txt.файла..
пробую так:

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

   FileDialog fdlg;

fdlg = new FileDialog(  this, "Сохранение файла:..",  FileDialog.SAVE);
fdlg.show();

 File myfile = new File("test.txt");



String text1 = jTex.getText();



 try        {
       // запись всей строки
     BufferedWriter writer = new  BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myfile));
        polnijput = fdlg.getDirectory();
        writer.write(text1);

        // запись по символам

      //  writer.append('E');

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }
    catch(IOException ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 



}
```

Comment: а проблема в чем?

Comment: не сохраняет содержимое поля Jtex в txt файл. диалоговое окно открывается. но вот файл не сохраняется(хоть и проходит без ошибки)

Comment: так `myfile` у вас указывает на `test.txt` всегда. В вашем же недавнем вопросе было взятие файла из `FileDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Write a small string to a File - Use a FileWriter
 */
public static void useFileWriter(String content, String filePath) {
    Writer writer = null;

    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
        writer.write(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Messages.getInstance().error("Error writing the file : " + filePath, e);

    } finally {

        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Messages.getInstance().error("Error closing the file : " + filePath, e);
            }
        }

    }
}


public static void writeToFile(String fullFilePath, String text)
{
    BufferedWriter output = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fullFilePath);
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.append(text);
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        Messages.getInstance().error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if ( output != null )
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Messages.getInstance().error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь.